# Uninstalling microsoft sql server

Tags: windows

So I've been doing a little cleaning and noticed a lot of SQL servers installed. Do I need all of them or can I remove them? (or are they needed for some games like c++ redistributable?) I do not have visual studio installed anymore so it won't be needed for that. At least for now.

[image]

Comment: You must have installed them for a reason.  None of the software you list in the screenshot is actual MS SQL Server by the way.  Just tools to connect to it.  If you don't want it installed, just remove it, if it's required by something else that is installed you can simply reinstall it.

Comment: Although Visual Studio will indeed install MS SQL Server, its not the only program that does so. It would be best to open MS Visual Studio Management Tools to figure out what databases are currently there and try to match them with any program you have. If they don't show any databases, then you can safely delete the program. Note, Windows by default uses MS SQL for logs and stuff, so you will most likely see one or two databases. Google the database names to find out more.